# How to Sorting Mutable Array of NSNumbers using for Loop in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, loops

I tried this, but I am not successful. Can any one sort this problem?

```
 NSNumber *num1= [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    NSNumber *num2= [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    NSNumber *num3= [NSNumber numberWithInt:7];
    NSNumber *num4= [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
    NSNumber *num5= [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];



    NSMutableArray *array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:num1,num2,num3,num4,num5, nil];

    int numLength = [array count];

    int tempValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLength; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numLength; j++)
        {
            NSNumber *temp=[array objectAtIndex:i];
            int first =[temp integerValue];

            NSNumber *temp1=[array objectAtIndex:j+1];
            int second =[temp1 integerValue];

            if(first > second)

            {
                tempValue = second;

                [array replaceObjectAtIndex:j+1 withObject:temp];
                [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:temp1];

            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Array is %@", array);
```

This code is in ViewDidLoad...

Thanks

Comment: why is it necessary to create _two_ instances of `NSMutableArray` class?

Comment: `-sortUsingComparator:`!!! are you a bubble sort troll? ;)

Comment: I don't want to use build-in Methods, I want using for loop. I am doing mistake in inner loop. @Michael

Comment: @Veer, what is wrong with the build-in methods? those'd use the much more efficient B-trees... `O(lg(n))` vs. `O(n*n)`? geez...

Comment: Sir, issue is that I am trying to make it using for loop. There is nothing wrong with build-in, I know they are easy to use and simple. but i want logic of it.

Comment: @holex well, it's `O(n log(n))`, not `O(log(n))`.. but I agree that its much better than `O(n^2)`!! so you're basically right!

Comment: @Michael, yes, you are right, my mistake. but I'm still shocked by the OP...

Comment: @holex He is just trying to make sorting by himself. What's wrong with learning?

Comment: @Veer the algorithm you use is called bubble sort. It's the most inefficient sort algorithm there is. (academic note: it's of course possible to construct a `O(2^n)` algorithm too, but that would be just crazy.)

Comment: SO, what is best algorithm for this @Michael, I want using for loop. So, not matter either it is efficient or not. I need to solve it :)

Comment: @Veer, if you would really like to practice, I'd recommend to implement B-trees, that would be really educational; this one is just pathetic. no offense, of course.

Comment: @holex hmmm, if the OP insists on using a for-loop, do you think he will be able to implement a B-tree? seriously ;) i prefer merge-sort btw...

Comment: @Michael, yes, iteration is necessary for B-trees as well for sorting, adding, removing, and additionally re-factoring the B-trees – the bubble-algorithm'd be challenging for a 13-14 years old child in Computer Science class, maybe. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, it works well indeed:

```
NSMutableArray *_array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { [_array addObject:@(arc4random()%10)]; }

NSLog(@"random: %@", _array);

for (int i = 0; i < _array.count; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < _array.count; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            NSInteger _first = [[_array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
            NSInteger _second = [[_array objectAtIndex:j] integerValue];
            if (_second < _first) {
                [_array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"sorted : %@", _array);
```

*NOTE: this way to sort an array's elements is highly inefficient, it is recommended to use only educational purpose.*

Comment: @Michael, this was the OP about, finding a problem in his algorithm. sorted in 2 minutes. I would recommend to use any of the group `sortUsing...:` methods. I'm not doing the practice instead of him. :)

Comment: @Michael, he can find thousand explanation of how the the B-trees works in theory, and the same amount of pseudo codes is still available for making the final implementation, if he is not smart enough to develop the algorithm using the mathematical model for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSNumber *num1= [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSNumber *num2= [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
NSNumber *num3= [NSNumber numberWithInt:7];
NSNumber *num4= [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
NSNumber *num5= [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,nil];

int numLength = [array count];
for (int i = 0; i < numLength-1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < numLength; j++)
    {
        NSNumber *temp=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        int first =[temp integerValue];

        NSNumber *temp1=[array objectAtIndex:j];
        int second =[temp1 integerValue];

        if(first > second)
        {
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:temp];
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:temp1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same problem which I am already facing, did you test this code.?

Comment: @Veer edited it NSNumber *temp1=[array objectAtIndex:j+1]; line was giving problem

Comment: @Veer also there is no need for tempValue

Comment: yet not sorted. see at your end. @rohamAM

Comment: 2014-06-27 14:59:27.870 Sorting[3208:70b] Array is (
    2,
    9,
    7,
    3,
    5
)

Comment: This is output, disarranged.

Comment: @Veer int j = i+1 NOT int j = 1

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
NSNumber *num1= [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    NSNumber *num2= [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    NSNumber *num3= [NSNumber numberWithInt:7];
    NSNumber *num4= [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
    NSNumber *num5= [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

    NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,nil];
    int tempValue;

    int numLength = [array count];
    for (int i = 0; i < numLength-1; i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        for(; j < numLength-1; j++)
        {
            NSNumber *temp=[array objectAtIndex:i];
            int first =[temp integerValue];

            NSNumber *temp1=[array objectAtIndex:j];
            int second =[temp1 integerValue];

            if(first < second)
            {
                 tempValue = second;
                [array replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:temp];
                [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:temp1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, the famous Bubble Sort:

```
static void bubble_sort()
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [@[@5,@3,@7,@9,@2] mutableCopy];

    BOOL haveSwappedSomething;
    do
    {
        haveSwappedSomething = NO;
        for(int i=0; i<([array count]-1); i++) {
            NSNumber *num1 = array[i];
            NSNumber *num2 = array[i+1];
            if([num1 intValue] > [num2 intValue]) {
                array[i] = num2;
                array[i+1] = num1;
                haveSwappedSomething = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    while(haveSwappedSomething);

    NSLog(@"Array is %@", array);
}
```

Time complexity: `O(n^2)` (worst case and average case) (="crappy")

Space complexity: `O(1)` (worst case) (because it's in-place just like some variants of quicksort) (="excellent")

Its of course better to use quicksort because its `O(n log n)` / `O(1)` regarding time/space.